# WPF ListBox Style update doens't work

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, styles

I have created a `WPF ListBox` and set an `itemcontainerstyle` that bind to a property and converts it to a valid color.
This works when the Listbox is initially loaded, so no problem with the bindings or the converter.

```
           <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Diensten}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDienst, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" Background="Transparent">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=IsActive, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToListBoxBgColorConverter}}" />
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerik:Label Content="{Binding Path=Dienst.Description}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

But when my selectedItem is changed i trigger the PropertyChangedMethod in the refreshView method to update my ListBox.
But unfortunatly my style is not applied to the new value of the binding.

So it seems the style that was initially created for my listbox didn't get updated

```
    Public Property Diensten() As List(Of ToegangDienst)
        Get
            Return _diensten
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of ToegangDienst))
            _diensten = value
            FirePropertyChanged("Diensten")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property SelectedDienst() As ToegangDienst
        Get
            Return _selectedDienst
        End Get
        Set(value As ToegangDienst)
            If Diensten.Contains(value) Then
                UpdateDienstToDetails(value)
                _selectedDienst = value
                FirePropertyChanged("SelectedDienst")
                RefreshView()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property


   Private Sub RefreshView()
        FirePropertyChanged("Diensten")
        FirePropertyChanged("IsBusy")
        FirePropertyChanged("IsVisible")
        _ribbonViewModel.EvaluateCommands()
    End Sub
```

Any suggestions how to get the style to update also?

Now the strange thing is that i manage to solve the problem no by firing the property changed method but by this line of code:

```
Diensten = Diensten.AsEnumerable().ToList()
```

I have a working solution but i'd prefer some cleaner way to achieve this.

Comment: If I understand your IsActive Property won't fire the style right? where do you manage the changes of this property in your code behind?

Comment: My ListBox is bound to : Diensten (List(Of Dienst))  When this list is updated with propertychanged, it is redered but the style is not

Answer (score 0):

My `List(Of ToegangDienst)` didn't need to be observable because I was not adding or removing anything from it, but apparently this also caused it to not update the entire List when firing the `PropertyChanged` method.

I changed my

```
List(Of ToegangDienst)
```

to

```
ObservableCollection(Of ToegangDienst)
```

And it worked when I called

```
_selectedToegangDienst.FirePropertyChanged("IsActive")
```